# iphone game runs on devices. crash on specific level in simulator

Tags: c++, iphone, opengl-es, ios-simulator

i have developed a game that is currently running on iphone/ipad/ipod touch without any problems.
recently i needed to run it on the simulator, and i found that it crashes on a specific load function when starting one of the levels, i went to the crash report in user/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports and saw that abort() is being called after the constructor of one of the game objects is called:

```
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x93100ef6 __kill + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x93100ee8 kill$UNIX2003 + 32
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x9319362d raise + 26
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x931a9679 __abort + 124
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x9318c3bc release_file_streams_for_task + 0
5   gamehere                        0x0004d650 Piso::Piso(W3d*, int, int) + 758 (Piso.cpp:45)
```

so i go to "Piso.cpp" and see that line 45 is just the ending bracket of the constructor for this object.

i really dont have a clue of what can be the cause of this crash, inside that constructor i load textures, initialize some counters, arrays and other stuff for that class, again, any of those have caused problems when running on devices...

i really appreciate some ideas on where to look in order to fix this.
Thanks!.

Comment: Can you give us the full code of the constructor? Close bracket means the destructor of some local variable...

Comment: Are both simulator and iPhone OS versions the same ?

Comment: yes, they are exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A close bracket means the destructor of some local variable. For example:

```
struct Test {
    ~Test() {
        throw "error";
    }
}

int main() {
    int b;
    {
        Test a;
    };    //On your stack trace, here it will be pointed as the error line.
    b = 1;
};
```

Comment: thanks i´ll check local variables in the function. sorry for not posting the code for that constructor, mostly because of calls to propietary objects. will comment back.

Comment: Done!. you gave me the right clue, it was a local array that got out of boundaries in one of the cases. too bad i got a down vote on the question, i assume for not posting the full code.. Anyway, thanks again for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I would not worry at all as long as it works on the actual devices, the simulators cannot reproduce 100% what a device can do.